# How to make DataSpell display the runtime of a cell？

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jetbrains-ide, dataspell

like VS Code
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ovil8.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3):

It works for me:

```
pip install ipython-autotime
```

Once you have loaded it, any cell run after this ,will give you the execution time of the cell:

```
%load_ext autotime
```

Answer (score -1):

Per the [VS Code documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support-py#_jupyter-code-cells), running an active Jupyter Notebook cell involves the **Python: Run Selection/Line in Python Terminal** command, or <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Your line of code `from kaggle_house_price_base import train_features, train_labels` is a [module](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html) import statement — see [Best practices when importing in IPython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22144748/best-practices-when-importing-in-ipython) and [How to correctly import a Python module in VS Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59702230/how-to-correctly-import-a-python-module-in-vs-code) for additional informaiton.

Comment: I just wanted to emphasize the 2.6s at the bottom

Comment: I mean, did you even read the question?